# pass direct reference or closure

Tags: swift, closures

Coming from a different language background where passing a method to another object was done differently as demonstrated below (approach A) but I've noticed a style of passing blocks around in Objective-C as well as SWIFT, what's the recommended way in SWIFT and why? (pros and cons any?)

```
class Messenger {
    private var _method: ((String) -> ())

    init(method: (String -> ())) {
        _method = method
    }
}

class Test {
    init() {
        Messenger(method: self.callback) //approach A

        Messenger({
            message in self.callback(message) //approach B - Wrapper/Block style
        })
    }

    func callback(message: String) {
        println(message)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method A is the way to go.  Method B really doesn’t serve a purpose – you are declaring an anonymous function which takes a single parameter and does nothing to it but use it as an argument to another function, `callback`.  It’s essentially like saying this:

```
func f(arg1: Int) {
    // do nothing but call g
    g(arg1)
}
f(1)        // no different to calling g(1)
takeFunc(f) // no different to passing in g
```

It’s important to realize that a function declared with the closure expression syntax, `let f: Int->Bool = { i in etc }`, and a function declared with the `func` keyword, `func f(i: Int)->Bool { etc }` amount to much the same thing.  There are subtle differences but not fundamental ones.

Re your concerns about strong references – the closure expression in option B doesn’t really help the situation.  In option A you pass an implicit reference to self by passing in a pointer to an instance's member function.  In Option B, you declare an anonymous closure that “captures” `self`, and then pass that, but that anonymous function being stored will keep `self` alive in just the same way storing `self.memfun` will, just with an extra level of indirection.  In fact, it’s so easy to forget that capturing `self` via a closure expression can be a risk that Swift will warn you if you do it implicitly by accident and force you to put an explicit `self` in there (which can be super-annoying sometimes when you know the capture isn’t an issue e.g. when referencing `self` in a call to `map` or `filter`).

To write a callback function that didn’t capture self, you would have to use a [capture list](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH20-XID_103):

```
    Messenger { [weak self] message in // weak or unowned depending on how Messenger is being used 
        self?.callback(message)  // if weak, self needs to be optional
        return // return needed since otherwise it will attempt to return ()?
    }
```

By the way, the best way to write more Swift-y Swift would be to ditch a lot of the excess brackets :-)

e.g.

```
// no need to wrap entire function type in (),
// and single argument types (i.e. 1-element tuples)
// don’t need () surrounding them: 
private var _method: String -> ()
```

instead of

```
private var _method: ((String) -> ())
```

and

```
Messenger { // closure exprs can be outside the () of functions 
            // when they’re the last argument (and () can be 
            // left out completely when they’re the only argument) 
    message in self.callback(message)
}
```

instead of

```
Messenger({
        message in self.callback(message) //approach B - Wrapper/Block style
})
```

Comment: if there's a possibility of reference cycle, I should go with approach B while assigning `self` as weak reference

Comment: there’s some good into on [this page](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH20-XID_103)

Answer (score 0):

Your approach B will allow you to insert additional statements between `message in` and `self.callback(message)`. Without such additional statements (as in your verbatim example) I would favor approach A.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, my concern is such approach (approach A) is not seen as foreign or alienated here in SWIFT world, cause frankly I've not seen use of Approach A in SWIFT codes that I've seen around

Comment: and I think one drawback of approach A is memory leak problem, the reference can't be declared as weak